# GKE private loadbalancer / ingress service with path based routing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to create one private ingress / service of type LoadBalancer, and use it with multiple PODs with path-based routing. Is this possible?

I know that [Ingress with public endpoint supports path-based routing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_6_optional_serving_multiple_applications_on_a_load_balancer), but I'm looking for a loadbalancer with private endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question, yes it's possible. Note that you can use the [Internal Load Balancing (ILB) for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) that creates a private LoadBalancer Ingress IP in the cluster for receiving traffic within the same VPC region.

In addition, since you need to configure it using path-based routing, consider the following:
- It must be an Ingress, not a Service.
- Install an NGINX/Traefik IngressController.
- Expose it with an ILB Service.
- Add Ingresses whose annotations only specify they should create an NGINX/Traefik Ingress entry.